# Prioritized TPL DataFlow BufferBlock

Tags: task-parallel-library, priority-queue, tpl-dataflow

It should be something very natural to have, I was wondering if there is a ready implementation of Prioritized BufferBlock from TPL DataFlow library?

Comment: How would you expect it to behave with regards to `BoundedCapacity`? Or is that a feature you don't need?

Comment: @svick I'd expect that if `BoundedCapacity` was reached, then it would drop the item at the end of the list.  Not exactly optimal, but it's one approach.  Another would be to always set `BoundedCapacity` to `DataflowBlockOptions` to `Unbounded`.

Comment: I'd be cautious about such a block. All existing dataflow blocks have a guarantee that message ordering is preserved. This would violate that apparent guarantee.

Comment: Everywhere I look, no one seem to realise the valid need for a priority queue. And I cannot understand way. In low level IO operations (and even in high level IO operations) prioritised queuing is very essential. @husayt, have you had any luck with a solution to your problem yet?

Comment: Related: [TPL DataFlow, link blocks with priority?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974228/tpl-dataflow-link-blocks-with-priority)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the best way to achieve this is to use a specialised **Task Scheduler**, rather than implementing your own BufferBlock. There are many variety of them one can find out in net. For instance, check `QueuedTaskScheduler` in [ParallelExtensions Library](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/09/9990424.aspx)