# TPL DataFlow, link blocks with priority?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

Using TPL.DataFlow blocks, is it possible to link two or more sources to a single ITargetBlock(e.g. ActionBlock) and prioritize the sources?

e.g.

```
BufferBlock<string> b1 = new ...
BufferBlock<string> b2 = new ...
ActionBlock<string> a = new ...

//somehow force messages in b1 to be processed before any message of b2, always
b1.LinkTo (a);
b2.LinkTo (a);
```

As long as there are messages in b1, I want those to be fed to "a" and once b1 is empty, b2 messages are beeing pushed into "a"

Ideas?

Answer (score 15):

There is nothing like that in TPL Dataflow itself.

The simplest way I can imagine doing this by yourself would be to create a structure that encapsulates three blocks: high priority input, low priority input and output. Those blocks would be simple `BufferBlock`s, along with a method forwarding messages from the two inputs to the output based on priority, running in background.

The code could look like this:

```
public class PriorityBlock<T>
{
    private readonly BufferBlock<T> highPriorityTarget;

    public ITargetBlock<T> HighPriorityTarget
    {
        get { return highPriorityTarget; }
    }

    private readonly BufferBlock<T> lowPriorityTarget;

    public ITargetBlock<T> LowPriorityTarget
    {
        get { return lowPriorityTarget; }
    }

    private readonly BufferBlock<T> source;

    public ISourceBlock<T> Source
    {
        get { return source; }
    }

    public PriorityBlock()
    {
        var options = new DataflowBlockOptions { BoundedCapacity = 1 };

        highPriorityTarget = new BufferBlock<T>(options);
        lowPriorityTarget = new BufferBlock<T>(options);
        source = new BufferBlock<T>(options);

        Task.Run(() => ForwardMessages());
    }

    private async Task ForwardMessages()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.WhenAny(
                highPriorityTarget.OutputAvailableAsync(),
                lowPriorityTarget.OutputAvailableAsync());

            T item;

            if (highPriorityTarget.TryReceive(out item))
            {
                await source.SendAsync(item);
            }
            else if (lowPriorityTarget.TryReceive(out item))
            {
                await source.SendAsync(item);
            }
            else
            {
                // both input blocks must be completed
                source.Complete();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage would look like this:

```
b1.LinkTo(priorityBlock.HighPriorityTarget);
b2.LinkTo(priorityBlock.LowPriorityTarget);
priorityBlock.Source.LinkTo(a);
```

For this to work, `a` also has to have `BoundingCapacity` set to one (or at least a very low number).

The caveat with this code is that it can introduce latency of two messages (one waiting in the output block, one waiting in `SendAsync()`). So, if you have a long list of low priority messages and suddenly a high priority message comes in, it will be processed only after those two low-priority messages that are already waiting.

If this is a problem for you, it can be solved. But I believe it would require more complicated code, that deals with the less public parts of TPL Dataflow, like [`OfferMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160309).

Comment: Thanks, but in my case I do have to always process the high priority messages directly. it turns out that DataFlow is too slow for my usecase anyway so I have a handrolled solution right now.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an implementation of a `PriorityBufferBlock<T>` class, that propagates high priority items more frequently than low priority items. The constructor of this class has a `priorityPrecedence` parameter, that defines how many high priority items will be propagated for each low priority item. If this parameter has the value `1.0` (the smallest valid value), there is no real priority to speak of. If this parameter has the value `Double.PositiveInfinity`, no low priority item will ever be propagated as long as there are high priority items in the queue. If this parameter has a more normal value, like `5.0` for example, one low priority item will be propagated for every 5 high priority items.

This class maintains internally two queues, one for high and one for low priority items. The number of items stored in each queue is not taken into account, unless one of the two lists is empty, in which case all items of the other queue are freely propagated on demand. The `priorityPrecedence` parameter influences the behavior of the class only when both internal queues are non-empty. Otherwise, if only one queue has items, the `PriorityBufferBlock<T>` behaves like a normal `BufferBlock<T>`.

```
public class PriorityBufferBlock<T> : IPropagatorBlock<T, T>,
    IReceivableSourceBlock<T>
{
    private readonly IPropagatorBlock<T, int> _block;
    private readonly Queue<T> _highQueue = new();
    private readonly Queue<T> _lowQueue = new();
    private readonly Predicate<T> _hasPriorityPredicate;
    private readonly double _priorityPrecedence;
    private double _priorityCounter = 0;

    private object Locker => _highQueue;

    public PriorityBufferBlock(Predicate<T> hasPriorityPredicate,
        double priorityPrecedence,
        DataflowBlockOptions dataflowBlockOptions = null)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(hasPriorityPredicate);
        if (priorityPrecedence < 1.0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(priorityPrecedence));
        _hasPriorityPredicate = hasPriorityPredicate;
        _priorityPrecedence = priorityPrecedence;
        dataflowBlockOptions ??= new();
        _block = new TransformBlock<T, int>(item =>
        {
            bool hasPriority = _hasPriorityPredicate(item);
            Queue<T> selectedQueue = hasPriority ? _highQueue : _lowQueue;
            lock (Locker) selectedQueue.Enqueue(item);
            return 0;
        }, new()
        {
            BoundedCapacity = dataflowBlockOptions.BoundedCapacity,
            CancellationToken = dataflowBlockOptions.CancellationToken,
            MaxMessagesPerTask = dataflowBlockOptions.MaxMessagesPerTask
        });
        this.Completion = _block.Completion.ContinueWith(completion =>
        {
            Debug.Assert(this.Count == 0 || !completion.IsCompletedSuccessfully);
            lock (Locker) { _highQueue.Clear(); _lowQueue.Clear(); }
            return completion;
        }, default, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously |
            TaskContinuationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default).Unwrap();
    }

    public Task Completion { get; private init; }
    public void Complete() => _block.Complete();
    void IDataflowBlock.Fault(Exception exception) => _block.Fault(exception);
    public int Count
    {
        get { lock (Locker) return _highQueue.Count + _lowQueue.Count; }
    }

    private Queue<T> GetSelectedQueue(bool forDequeue)
    {
        Debug.Assert(Monitor.IsEntered(Locker));
        Queue<T> selectedQueue;
        if (_highQueue.Count == 0)
            selectedQueue = _lowQueue;
        else if (_lowQueue.Count == 0)
            selectedQueue = _highQueue;
        else if (_priorityCounter + 1 > _priorityPrecedence)
            selectedQueue = _lowQueue;
        else
            selectedQueue = _highQueue;
        if (forDequeue)
        {
            if (_highQueue.Count == 0 || _lowQueue.Count == 0)
                _priorityCounter = 0;
            else if (++_priorityCounter > _priorityPrecedence)
                _priorityCounter -= _priorityPrecedence + 1;
        }
        return selectedQueue;
    }

    private T Peek()
    {
        Debug.Assert(Monitor.IsEntered(Locker));
        Debug.Assert(_highQueue.Count > 0 || _lowQueue.Count > 0);
        return GetSelectedQueue(false).Peek();
    }

    private T Dequeue()
    {
        Debug.Assert(Monitor.IsEntered(Locker));
        Debug.Assert(_highQueue.Count > 0 || _lowQueue.Count > 0);
        return GetSelectedQueue(true).Dequeue();
    }

    private class TargetProxy : ITargetBlock<int>
    {
        private readonly PriorityBufferBlock<T> _parent;
        private readonly ITargetBlock<T> _realTarget;

        public TargetProxy(PriorityBufferBlock<T> parent, ITargetBlock<T> target)
        {
            Debug.Assert(parent is not null);
            _parent = parent;
            _realTarget = target ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(target));
        }

        public Task Completion => throw new NotSupportedException();
        public void Complete() => _realTarget.Complete();
        void IDataflowBlock.Fault(Exception error) => _realTarget.Fault(error);

        DataflowMessageStatus ITargetBlock<int>.OfferMessage(
            DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader, int messageValue,
            ISourceBlock<int> source, bool consumeToAccept)
        {
            Debug.Assert(messageValue == 0);
            if (consumeToAccept) throw new NotSupportedException();
            lock (_parent.Locker)
            {
                T realValue = _parent.Peek();
                DataflowMessageStatus response = _realTarget.OfferMessage(
                    messageHeader, realValue, _parent, consumeToAccept);
                if (response == DataflowMessageStatus.Accepted) _parent.Dequeue();
                return response;
            }
        }
    }

    public IDisposable LinkTo(ITargetBlock<T> target,
        DataflowLinkOptions linkOptions)
            => _block.LinkTo(new TargetProxy(this, target), linkOptions);

    DataflowMessageStatus ITargetBlock<T>.OfferMessage(
        DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader, T messageValue,
        ISourceBlock<T> source, bool consumeToAccept)
            => _block.OfferMessage(messageHeader,
                messageValue, source, consumeToAccept);

    T ISourceBlock<T>.ConsumeMessage(DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader,
        ITargetBlock<T> target, out bool messageConsumed)
    {
        _ = _block.ConsumeMessage(messageHeader, new TargetProxy(this, target),
            out messageConsumed);
        if (messageConsumed) lock (Locker) return Dequeue();
        return default;
    }

    bool ISourceBlock<T>.ReserveMessage(DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader,
        ITargetBlock<T> target)
            => _block.ReserveMessage(messageHeader, new TargetProxy(this, target));

    void ISourceBlock<T>.ReleaseReservation(DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader,
        ITargetBlock<T> target)
            => _block.ReleaseReservation(messageHeader, new TargetProxy(this, target));

    public bool TryReceive(Predicate<T> filter, out T item)
    {
        if (filter is not null) throw new NotSupportedException();
        if (((IReceivableSourceBlock<int>)_block).TryReceive(null, out _))
        {
            lock (Locker) item = Dequeue(); return true;
        }
        item = default; return false;
    }

    public bool TryReceiveAll(out IList<T> items)
    {
        if (((IReceivableSourceBlock<int>)_block).TryReceiveAll(out IList<int> items2))
        {
            T[] array = new T[items2.Count];
            lock (Locker)
                for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                    array[i] = Dequeue();
            items = array; return true;
        }
        items = default; return false;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
var bufferBlock = new PriorityBufferBlock<SaleOrder>(x => x.HasPriority, 2.5);
```

The above implementation supports all the features of the built-in [`BufferBlock<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.bufferblock-1), except from the [`TryReceive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.ireceivablesourceblock-1.tryreceive) with not-null `filter`. The core functionality of the block is delegated to an internal [`TransformBlock<T, int>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.transformblock-2), that contains a dummy zero value for every item stored in one of the queues.